# Hibernate Groupby sum

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to get groupby sum in hibernate.But there was an error called "java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to" and how to fix this?

This is what I want

```
select sum(this_.actual_qty), this_.c_code from m_crop_projections this_ where this_.cc_code='1089' and this_.entered_date='2018-03-22' group by this_.c_code
```

Hibernate

```
@Override
public List<CropProjections> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {
    System.out.println("inside repo-----"+colCode);
    System.out.println("inside repo-----"+date);
    Date convert_date = getUtilDate(date);

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(CropProjections.class, "cp");

    ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
    projList.add(Projections.alias(Projections.sum("actualqty"),"cp.actualqty"));
    projList.add(Projections.groupProperty("cropcode"));


    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("colcode", colCode));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("entereddate", convert_date));
    criteria.setProjection(projList);
    return criteria.list();
}
```

Service Class

```
@Override
@Transactional
public List<CropProjectionsDTO> getTotalReadyQty(String colCode, String date) {
    List<CropProjectionsDTO> list = new ArrayList<CropProjectionsDTO>();
    List<CropProjections> cropPrcojections = cropProjectionsDAO.getTotalReadyQty(colCode,date);     

    System.out.println(cropPrcojections);

    if (cropPrcojections.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.println("cropPrcojections Data Null-------");
    } else {
        System.out.println("cropPrcojections Data not-Null-------");
        for (CropProjections cropPro : cropPrcojections) {

            CropProjectionsDTO dto = new CropProjectionsDTO();
            dto.setActualqty(cropPro.getActualqty());
            dto.setCropcode(cropPro.getCropcode());

            System.out.println(cropPro.getActualqty());
            System.out.println(cropPro.getCropcode());
            list.add(dto);
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

The error occured in the for loop that in Service class.However cropPrcojections have values that parsing from by hibernate query.Error is cropPrcojections can't cast to cropPro..How to fix this?

Comment: 1. Post the whole stacktrace and not cut it off on the important parts... 2. Show your `CropProjections` class 3. Show us what the current query looks like and not just what you want it to look like

Comment: where are your calling the method `doInHibernate`?